# How to custom filename in a rolling Log4Net logfile start by *.log.1?

Tags: c#, log4net

Generally log4net creates rolling files as follows when the file reaches the given size limit.

```
trace.log
trace.log.1
trace.log.2
```

Is it possible to create the rolling files start by *.log.1 as below.

```
trace.log.1
trace.log.2
trace.log.3
```

Any ideas on the best way to implement this, assuming that it's possible?

Cheers

Oosutsuke

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use RollingFileAppender- log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender. Documentation for this available here: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#rollingfileappender

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks feedback! But i want the log file to start with "trace.log.1", not "trace.log".
Is it possible to config log4net as that?